# Dots in my Anchors in Nav Bar

Tags: html, css

Doing some basic html/css.  I was making a rudimentary navbar with floated links.  After getting it working I was stuck with this problem, and so far have not come to a solution.

My links have these dots in them. As the picture shows.

[image: 1]

My code is simple:

HTML

```
            <div id="nav-wrapper">
                <div id="navbar">
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the CSS

```
#nav-wrapper {
background-color: black;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
border-top: 2px solid gray;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

#navbar {
}

ul#nav li { 
float: left;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav * a {
width: 25px;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

My question is what is causing these dots?  And why don't they appear if I add more words/links to the list or I erase all but one item?  It's odd.  I must be missing something extremely embarrassing  because this just seems odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style:

```
list-style-type: none;
```

To this selector:

```
ul#nav li
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the code - list-style: none;

so your code will look like

```
ul#nav li { 
float: left;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your declaration for `ul#nav li` to include this property

```
list-style:none;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bcDDk/